# OrderBy child property linq to sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

Could someone help me with ordering nested collection in linq to sql. See my example below:

```
    public class A
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public virtual ICollection<A> ListA { get; set; }
    }
```

Call for data from db:

```
_unitOfWork.DbContext.B
            .OrderByDescending(ev => ev.ListA.OrderBy(a => a.Id))
            .ToList();
```

I case when ListA not empty all works fine. But if List A is empty i get an exception says that at least one object needs to implement IComparable. Is there a way to overcome that problem ?

Comment: When `ListA` is empty? Or when `ListA` is null?

Comment: @xdtTransform null

Comment: For a B like `new[] {
                        new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 3 },new A { Id = 1 },new A { Id = 2 }} }
                        ,new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 3 },new A { Id = 1 }} }
                        ,new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 999 }} }
                        ,new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 3 },new A { Id = 1 },new A { Id = 2 },new A { Id = 4 }} }
                        ,new B{ListA = new List<A>{} }
                        ,new B{ListA = null }
                    };`. What is the expected result? order list by number of element? Max? Sum?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order by null. null does not implement IComparable obviously.
Add a where clause before the orderby to check if listA is not null.

```
_unitOfWork.DbContext.B
        .Where(ev => ev.ListA != null)
        .OrderByDescending(ev => ev.ListA.OrderBy(a => a.Id))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: in this case we just restrict loading parent entities which has null ListA. But i 'm looking for a way of loading all entities in spite of null. But apply filtering only for  not null entities

Comment: well you are not filtering, you are ordering. And you cannot order null values.

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to have the B with Something in ListA, then Bs with empty collection, then Bs with Null reference.
With a ListA that is also ordered, you can check for null and empty list, then order based on that.

```
var Bs = new[] {
    new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 3 },new A { Id = 1 },new A { Id = 2 }} }
    ,new B{ListA = new List<A>{} }
    ,new B{ListA = null }
};

var result = Bs.Select(b =>
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    if (b.ListA == null)
                    {
                        i = 2;
                    }
                    else if (!b.ListA.Any())
                    {
                        i = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        b.ListA = b.ListA.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToList();
                    }
                    return new { oIndex = i, value = b };
                })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.oIndex)
                .Select(g => g.value);
```

You stated : *"when ListA not empty all works fine"*; I'm not sure to understand how. As the following code will throw without any null or empty collection.

```
var Bis = new[] {
            new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 3 },new A { Id = 1 },new A { Id = 2 }} }
            ,new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 3 },new A { Id = 1 }} }
            ,new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 999 }} }
            ,new B{ListA = new []{ new A { Id = 3 },new A { Id = 1 },new A { Id = 2 },new A { Id = 4 }} }
        };
var result = Bis.OrderByDescending(ev => ev.ListA.OrderBy(a => a.Id)).ToList();
```

Il you are comparing list you need to compare them on something. Is {1, 2, 3} bigger than {1,1,1,1}? How is {1,2,3} compare to {999, 999}? {2} and {1,1}? Because it has more element? Bigger value? What if one has bigger value but the others sum is twice bigger? For 2 list of 0s.. you base you comparaison on Sum and Value?